# QNetworkAccessManager freezes if network is unreachable

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, qnetworkaccessmanager

If network is unavailable and I'm doing post using `QNetworkAccessManager`, it will not give me error. It just freezes.

Is it possible to detect this situation?

I can't use timeout because of sometimes I need to upload big files and timeout will break upload process in this case.

Comment: need code. too broad.

Comment: In case of uploading or downloading big files you can listen to `QNetworkReply::uploadProgress` or `QNetworkReply::downloadProgress` signals and extend current timout.